# How can I check if a string appears in an array more than once?

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, match

I'd like to check if a string appears in an array more than once. There is a way I found but it requires installing something from CPAN. I don't have root access to be able to install the CPAN module in question so I would prefer to do this without using CPAN.

Comment: First, you do not have to be `root` to use CPAN modules, but that's another topic. Second,  **what have you tried**? You can't even write a simple loop to go through an array?

Comment: What is the name of the CPAN module you found? Which functions seemed useful?  What have you tried so far? You can marginally improve this question (which is a really a FAQ) by adding a bit more information so that it becomes useful for other SO users.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $count = grep $_ eq $word, @array;
```

See [perldoc -f grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting `$_` to each element) and returns the list value consisting of those elements for which the expression evaluated to true. In scalar context, returns the number of times the expression was true.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:  I assumed your "string" was not necessarily a discrete element. To count each element that matches completely, tighten the match (i.e. with `/^...$/`) or use `eq` as Sinan points out in the comments.

---

You could count the number of times `grep` matches the string in the array:

```
my @animals = qw/duck goose camel squirrel camel camelback/ ;

if ( scalar ( grep { /^camel$/ } @animals ) > 1 ) { 
   print "more than one" ; 
}
```

Shorter forms:

```
say "more"  if (grep /^camel$/, @animals ) > 1 ;
say ~~( grep /^camel$/, @animal );
```

"`~~`" is short for "`scalar`" here.

Comment: oops yup `~~` not needed with `if`... forgot. Thanks.  I usually use these short lines in the `re.pl` or debugger to count matched elements instead of counting the exact number. I load up my favorite modules (for counting I use "`true`").  I've trashed things more than once with `grep = "camel" , @animals` (instead of `eq`).  Sorry for being sloppy.   Will fix for posterity.

Comment: @SinanÜnür - Edited as per comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When asking for help on Stack Overflow, it is generally expected that you show some code for us to help you *with*. This isn't the place to get a crash-course in Perl programming.

The most general-purpose way to deal with this is to build a hash whose keys are all the distinct values in the list, and the values are the number of times that item occurs. This program does exactly that to find the values that occur more than once

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @animals = qw/ duck goose camel squirrel camel /;

my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @animals;

say for grep $counts{$_} > 1, keys %counts;
```

**output**

```
camel
```

Or, if you have a specific value that you want to check whether it occurs multiple times, you can query the hash directly

```
if ( $counts{goose} > 1 ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The "`%seen` hash" seem to be the most idiomatic and robustly correct way to do this (with `grep $_ eq $match, @array;` being the simplest, but more prone to PEBKAC for me). As a bonus you make `++$count{$_}` look short and sweet here :-)  Wouldn't some more explicit syntax (but sugary in its own way) like `count("string", @array)` make a useful  addition to `List::Util` or `List::MoreUtils`?

Comment: So I guess now I want to learn about prototypes ?  ... Or, well, how to make `sub count($@) { my $string = shift; scalar grep $_ eq $string, @_ }`  or `sub count ($@) { my $s = shift; my %count;  ++$count{$_} for  @_ ; return $count{$s} ; }` feel more "built in".

Comment: Just noting that the above is not my idea ... so it might not be that bad ;-)  *e.g.* [`autobox::Core`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/autobox::Core) does something that feels "core-like"  involving "`->count()`": ... `say [qw/camel squirrel duck camelhair camel goose/]->count("camel")`.  But it's only "Core" as in `autobox::Core`